# mysql 2 tables updation/deletion based on condition

Tags: php, mysql

Hello friends I have 2 Mysql tables with 1:N relationship between category and category_Dates

Category:

```
ID  Category    Frequency
1   Cat A   Half-yearly
2   Cat B   Quarterly
```

category_Dates:

```
ID  CatID   Date
1   1   01-Jan-15
2   1   01-Jul-15
3   2   01-Jan-15
4   2   01-Apr-15
5   2   01-Jul-15
6   2   01-Oct-15
```

based on the category frequency I am entering number of records automatically in category_date. Eg
When category frequency = quarterly, I am entering 4 records in category_date with ID of that category. And dates will be entered later.

I am little confused if in case on wants to edit the frequency from halfyearly to yearly. How to change number of records. Please help with your valuable suggestions. I am using laravel 4 framework with mysql

Comment: Care to check answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the frequency in Category table, retrieve the update category_id,
delete all from category_dates where CatId=category_id then insert the new entries in category_Dates.
Hope this help.
I assume your models are Category and CategoryDates. 
let's update category id 1 from Half-yearlyto to Quarterly

```
$query = Category::find(1);
$query -> Frequency = 'Quarterly';
$query -> save();
return $query -> id;
```

in the CategoryDates model you would delete the catID = 1 and insert new data

```
$catID = 1;
$query = CategoryModel::where('CatId',$catId) -> delete();
$data = ['CatId' => $catID,'date' => 01-Jan-15, ....];
CategoryModel::create($data);
```

of course assuming that you would return the newly updated category id to your controller and call a funtionn to do the update in your CategoryModel. 
Hope this help.

Comment: Nope, pretty straight forward, delete entries and insert new entries.

Answer (score 1):

best way would be with 3rd table joining Dates and Categories. See little carefully ,you can see its **actually Many to Many relationship (N to N)** as 1 category can have multiple dates. and one date may be part of multiple categories, like say `01-Jan-15` is part of Category 1 and 2 as well.

So use

**category** table

`id  Category    Frequency
 1   Cat A   Half-yearly
 2   Cat B   Quarterly`

**date** table

`id Date
 1  01-Jan-15
 2  01-Apr-15
 3  01-Jul-15
 4  01-Oct-15`

**categories_dates** table

`ID  CatID   Date_id
1   1        1
2   1        3
3   2        1
4   2        2
5   2        3
6   2        4`

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of this but its complicating the entire process wherein previously I had to enter records in one table. Now I have to simultaneously enter records in two table. Also I have to use cascade for maintaining records integrity. Any suggestions